# PHP: Loop through SeekableIterator

Tags: php, seekableiterator

I work on a php project about resolving Cloud storage,like AWS EC2.

I try to return results look like `SplFileInfo` and `DirectoryIterator`.

First, I typed `FileInfo` to mock `SplFileInfo`

```
class FileInfo
{
    protected $file;

    public function __construct($file)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
    }

    public function getFilename()
    {
        return $this->file['filename'];
    }

    public function getSize()
    {
        return $this->file['size'];
    }

    ... other methods like SplFileInfo
}
```

Second, I typed `Directory` to mock `DirectoryIterator`

```
class Directory extends FileInfo implements SeekableIterator
{
    protected $files;
    protected $position;

    public function __construct($files)
    {
        $this->files = $files;
    }

    public function current()
    {
        return new FileInfo($this->files[$this->position]);
    }

    ... and other methods required by SeekableIterator
}
```

Then the problem is where I should istancing `FileInfo`, it is proper to instant an object on each `current()` called? or instant all objects on `__construct()`?

And why `DirectoryIterator` implements `SplFileInfo`, just for code hint?

Comment: Why are you "mocking" these classes? If you want PHP implementations, have a look at HHVM's implementation: https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/tree/master/hphp/system/php/spl

Comment: @Sbls I work on a project like amazon ec2 php sdk. so I want to return results look like `SplFileInfo` and `DirectoryIterator` for 'seamless' integration who using the SDK.